# Timing based events in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I want to create a music visualizer, and to do this I want to build an array which safes instructions in order of occurrence in the music. I then want to build a function that parses through the array at a set speed and performs the instructions.

So for example I have an array with {a,b,a,b,a} and for every a the screen turns red for every b the screen turns black.

I tried using Threads and the sleep() function but it wouldn't wake up again.
I'm frankly at a loss as to what to do next.

Comment: You have to make two threads to be synchronized. You cannot ```notify()``` (wake) others threads that are not synchronized together.

Comment: If you are new to SO, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask a good question.

Comment: @user3348521 would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417937/create-a-simple-countdown-in-processing/12421641#12421641) help ?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`modulo`](https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html) operator along with the [`frameCount`](https://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html) variable to do something every `X` frames.

Here's a little example that changes the background every `60` frames, or once per second:

```
void draw() {
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) {
    background(random(255), random(255), random(255));
  }
}
```

This uses hard-coded `60` to change the background once per second, but you could get that number from an array instead.