# Java slow time of animation in Processing

Tags: java, processing

I am using Processing
Is there anyway I can slow time of my multiple circle drawing animation ? It is supposed to look like a starry night , but it is too fast

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: @Aleksandar Djuric alternatively you can use [millis()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417937/create-a-simple-countdown-in-processing/12421641#12421641) to update the animation properties less often or make increments of your circle drawing properties smaller

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the framerate by calling the [frameRate function](https://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup() {frameRate(4);} void draw() {}
```