# How to make an object appear after a specific amount of time in Processing

Tags: arraylist, processing, delay

Im trying to make a program where you are a ship and you simply avoid comets that fly towards you. I somewhat know how to use array lists to add and subtract objects, but I'm not sure how to get the program to add and subtract objects after a specific time like 5 seconds. My goal is to make each comet spawn 2 seconds apart but I'm not sure how. If anyone can help please let me know!

Comment: Other than `frameCount` you can also look into [millis()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417937/create-a-simple-countdown-in-processing/12421641#12421641).

Answer (score 0):

Processing exposes a useful variable `frameCount` that you can use for such timing behaviours.

You could use it in combination with the modulo operator *%* (an operator that returns the remainder after the division of two numbers), as follows:

```
draw() {
    .
    .
    .
    if (frameCount % t == 0) {
        spawnComet();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Assuming `frameRate` is fixed at 60, `t` takes the value of 60*(desired time delay in seconds). You want to spawn comets every 2 seconds: 60*2 = 120. Therefore set `t` to 120 to satisfy the requirement of your example. This means `spawnComet()` will trigger every 120 frames.