# How can I clear/reset the canvas with a counter or countdown in Processing?

Tags: java, processing, counter, redraw

I would like to know how can I set a reset loop:
While the draw() is going on I would like to clear the canvas so I can start to draw on a clean canvas again and again.

(I don't want to use keyPressed() or mousePressed() it has to be automatic)

```
import ddf.minim.*;
Minim minim;
AudioInput in;

void setup() {
  minim = new Minim(this);
  minim.debugOn ();
  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.MONO, 100);
  fullScreen();
  background(255, 60, 80);
}

void draw() {
  float soundlevel;
  float distance_top = random(100);
  int t;
  int interval = 10;
  String time = "010";

  soundlevel = in.mix.get(0);

  stroke(255, random(90, 255));
  line(0, distance_top + soundlevel * 4000, width, distance_top + soundlevel * 1000);
  line(0, distance_top + soundlevel * 1000, width, distance_top + soundlevel * 4000);


  t = interval-int(millis()/100);
  time = nf(t, 3);
  if (t == 0) {
    redraw();
    interval = interval +10;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advice!

Comment: Please add the code of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply clear the background again, for example when you press a key:

```
void keyPressed(){
  background(255, 60, 80);
}
```

You can do the same on some other event (amount of time, loudness, etc.)

Here's an example based on your code that clears the background every 3 seconds:

```
import ddf.minim.*;
Minim minim;
AudioInput in;

//3s as millis
int interval = 3 * 1000;
int time;

void setup() {
  fullScreen();
  background(255, 60, 80);

  time = millis();

  minim = new Minim(this);
  //minim.debugOn ();
  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.MONO, 100);
}

void draw() {
  float soundlevel;
  float distance_top = random(100);

  soundlevel = in.mix.get(0);

  stroke(255, random(90, 255));
  line(0, distance_top + soundlevel * 4000, width, distance_top + soundlevel * 1000);
  line(0, distance_top + soundlevel * 1000, width, distance_top + soundlevel * 4000);

  if(millis() - time >= interval){
    // clear background
    background(255, 60, 80);
    // reset time for next interval
    time = millis();
    // debug
    println("=========================>  tick");
  }

}
```

For more info on millis() for a delay see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417937/create-a-simple-countdown-in-processing/12421641#12421641)

Another option is to do the calculation frame based using [`frameCount`](https://processing.org/reference/frameCount.html).
For example if the sketch's `frameRate` is about 60 fps and you want to clear roughly every 3 seconds you can check if the multiples of 180 (3 * 60) frames passed in tandem with the [modulo(%) operator](https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html)

```
import ddf.minim.*;
Minim minim;
AudioInput in;

void setup() {
  //fullScreen();
  size(300,300);
  background(255, 60, 80);

  minim = new Minim(this);
  //minim.debugOn ();
  in = minim.getLineIn(Minim.MONO, 100);
}

void draw() {
  float soundlevel;
  float distance_top = random(100);

  soundlevel = in.mix.get(0);

  stroke(255, random(90, 255));
  line(0, distance_top + soundlevel * 4000, width, distance_top + soundlevel * 1000);
  line(0, distance_top + soundlevel * 1000, width, distance_top + soundlevel * 4000);

  if(frameCount % (3 * 60) == 0){
    // clear background
    background(255, 60, 80);
    // debug
    println("=========================>  tick");
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to use keyPressed() or mousePressed() it has to be automatic, that's why I searched for a counter.

Comment: The longer code snippet above does just that every 3 seconds. Have you tried it ?